Jasper Report horizontal list not printing to new line
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.8.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.8.0-2ed8dfabb690ff337a5797129f2cd92902b0c87b  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="coolbeans" columnCount="2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="277" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d0012ce1-5444-4e16-b68a-afb75c6b8f93">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="coolbeans"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="b647f03c-261f-403f-975d-a5ac41c36483">
        <parameter name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <parameter name="a" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="b" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="c" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="d" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="e" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="f" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="g" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="h" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="i" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="j" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="k" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="l" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="QUANTITY" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="a" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="a"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[a]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="b" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="b"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[b]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="c" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="c"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[c]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="d" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="d"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[d]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="e" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="e"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[e]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="f" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="f"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[f]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="g" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="g"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[g]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="h" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="h"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[h]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="i" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="i"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[i]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="j" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="j"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[j]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="k" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="k"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[k]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="l" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="l"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[l]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="170" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="268" height="155" uuid="d7c2afff-4c4f-4e80-9b90-492fa26e9e98"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="8393b813-bb4a-4bbb-bdb8-0af5bc776552">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource($P{QUANTITY})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="155" width="268">
                        <rectangle radius="10">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="268" height="155" uuid="1f6aa7f0-297c-4a92-a952-1007b78ea0c7">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                        </rectangle>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="10" y="8" width="250" height="20" uuid="79fd2fc2-2bb1-4bc4-84ca-05911b8c2b00"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{c}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="10" y="130" width="172" height="20" uuid="7fa90576-b766-41fa-b26e-da0f98582548"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{a}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="4" y="30" width="52" height="20" forecolor="#0D0C0C" uuid="416d6516-873a-4910-9276-894db8110f1c"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[forgot6]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="4" y="50" width="52" height="20" forecolor="#0D0C0C" uuid="934ea96a-be29-4926-88ed-ffb3de86360f"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[k]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="4" y="70" width="52" height="20" forecolor="#0D0C0C" uuid="c0b38bc6-d48d-4c91-9ddd-ea15289b3436"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[i / forgot5]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="4" y="90" width="52" height="20" uuid="b02dfc35-b9a6-4bf6-b691-3b1bf9532856"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[forgot4]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="4" y="110" width="52" height="20" uuid="31982d8d-fb19-438c-bcfc-8eb219120f2b"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[f]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="52" y="29" width="4" height="20" uuid="039a585e-c2a3-409f-8399-88f1b73f6bdc"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="52" y="49" width="4" height="20" uuid="642040c1-e9f7-4b64-b7ff-ce1209c94c57"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="52" y="69" width="4" height="20" uuid="da5edd12-4424-49dc-a0af-6404d58e5085">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="52" y="89" width="4" height="20" uuid="fa08d8a3-c4e9-4435-a56d-74ecc427e31c">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="52" y="109" width="4" height="20" uuid="2a0c2039-3092-4598-842c-0df0bef3c88a">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="58" y="30" width="100" height="20" uuid="e5baea69-4d08-4bc9-a29b-3080d6697e35">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{j}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="58" y="50" width="100" height="20" uuid="acce7361-8f13-4b39-bcc8-772cdd58e2dd">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse($P{k}))]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="58" y="70" width="100" height="20" uuid="e6c74dae-974f-4dc9-a9c9-0e1b30bab060">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{i}+" / "+$P{e}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="58" y="90" width="140" height="20" uuid="a2d18946-12db-4193-84b1-427c0b44d9a7"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{b}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="58" y="110" width="100" height="20" uuid="6d557e0b-4b2f-461b-8289-e110c96e5bb6"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{f}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="158" y="30" width="38" height="20" forecolor="#0D0C0C" uuid="e5ff475d-e28a-4d2d-8be8-1027db0476c4">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[forgot1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="158" y="50" width="38" height="20" forecolor="#0D0C0C" uuid="2ecb442c-e820-49cb-a99e-82465274ec7f"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[forgot2]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="158" y="70" width="38" height="20" forecolor="#0D0C0C" uuid="110153c1-ccbd-4435-a4a3-d7616deca84e"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[forgot3]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="194" y="29" width="4" height="20" uuid="44201b53-ae60-4d80-88dd-e7ccda205099"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="194" y="49" width="4" height="20" uuid="75b6e66c-4db3-4410-80c1-ca8557cb5aa3"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="194" y="69" width="4" height="20" uuid="6f4fa910-c5a3-4813-85a1-676d2bcfdc15"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="200" y="30" width="68" height="20" uuid="50f8c5bd-98b0-441f-a303-6378fcd447ed">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{d}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="200" y="50" width="68" height="20" uuid="6fd3cbfa-10ec-4b15-92bf-09fe25f702f7">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{l}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="200" y="70" width="68" height="20" uuid="6d8f98bd-bf9f-44f8-af88-a89a2c56eaca">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Verdana" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{h}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="190" y="93" width="76" height="57" uuid="70e61d04-5b11-4767-90a1-c9a826dab1a7">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <jr:Code128>
                                <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$P{a}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                            </jr:Code128>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>

I am currently using jr:list to print out an element n number of times based on the "quantity" parameter.
It is currently populating column 1 fully then moving onto column 2, but I want it to go left and right as it goes down a new line/row (horizontal first then to new line if there is no space essentially). I have played around with the printOrder of both report and list, the number of columns, the cell width but to no avail.
sidenote: so stupid that you need a minimum of 10 reputation to post images and there is also the thing about getting classified as spam when putting links (to the pages I found potential solutions for but didnt work)

<band height="170" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>

I found out how, in addition to the printOrder of report and list, I had to also change the layout structure of the detail band to horizontal.
